# Load text area lines in a jList

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jlist

I have a textarea called `jTextArea2` and a list called `jList1`. The TextArea2 has a lot of lines (about 80) and I have to load each of them as item of a jList.

[image]

Here you see an example: the text on the 1st line of my jTextArea, must become the 1st item of my jList. I wrote this code at the moment:

```
   String[] lines = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");             
   jList1.setListData(lines);
```

How could I do this? I didn't find a solution looking around on the net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like

```
String[] items = jTextArea2.getText().split("\n");
```

Then instead of `jTextArea.getText().line[0]` use `items[0]`. A for-each loop would help.

```
DefaultListModel list = new DefaultListModel();
String[] items = jTextArea2.getText().split("\n");

for(String item : items) {
    list.addElement(item);
}

jList1.setModel(list);
```

Note that this will add blank lines to the list, and it will not add blank list items for each row of the text area.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi It's just an example. After calling `String[] items = jTextArea2.getText().split("\n");`, `items` is an array containing each line of the text area, so `items[0]` is the first line, `items[1]` is the second line, etc. So to add all the lines to the jList, add each element of the array `items` with a for loop or a for-each loop like I showed. On second thought I would call `items` `lines` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read the text from the text area:

```
 String txt = jTextArea.getText();
```

Split the text by line:

```
  String[] lines = txt.split("\n");
```

Set the list:

```
  jList.setListData(lines);
```

Comment: it doesn't need any loop? I have updated my question putting your code, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: split() and setListData() handle the loops for you. When you say "it doesn't work for me" what do you mean?